# Math Parser/Lexer - Token interface design

Tags: oop, parsing, typescript, lexer

Currently working on a small pet project, a Math Parser/Lexer and eventually solver for fun/learning. I've bashed out a basic prototype and am now looking to convert this into TypeScript to clean things up. Prototype can be found here https://github.com/chips5k/math-solver-prototype for those interested.

I am trying to come up with a clean interface based approach to dealing with my Tokens. I suspect i am looking at this the wrong way, but hopefully someone can offer useful advice.

In my TS design i have several interfaces, the base interface being Token, with NumericToken and FunctionToken extending these. I then have several classes that implement these interfaces such as: AdditionToken, VariableToken, NumberToken, PiToken, SineToken etc...

My problem is that in order to work with these interfaces i end up requiring methods to check the basic type e.g isNumeric, isFunction, isVariable or alternatively a direct type === TokenFactory.NUMERIC etc... This, to me, feels wrong as it basically voids the point of using an interface. I suspect that there is a nicer/cleaner more polymorphic approach i could take but unfortunately i'm out of ideas and have been unable to find info on what i am doing.

An example of  where things fall apart shows itself when attempting to solve a series of tokens:

```
if(t.isFunction()) {
   var a = stack.unshift();
   var b = stack.unshift();
   if(a.isNumeric() && b.isNumeric()){
       result.push(tokenFactory.create(t.evaluate<number>(a.evaluate<number>, b.evaluate<number>));
   } else {
     //return to stack and move on, e.g can't solve x + 1 directly
   }
} else {
   stack.push(t);
}
```

Basically looking for what is considered the ideal approach for handling a scenario like this, and i suspect it may be an alternate approach to the design.

TIA!

Comment: I should add - the code snippet above is purely to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basic type e.g isNumeric, isFunction, isVariable or alternatively a direct type === TokenFactory.NUMERIC etc... This, to me, feels wrong

Nope. This is fairly idiomatic as the type controls what functionality is there.

E.g you will see the TypeScript `checker.ts` littered with check on `.kind` ([SyntaxKind](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/ast-tip-syntaxkind.html)) which is at TypeScript AST nodes discriminator.

Also you might want to consider adding a visitor that is recursive e.g.

```
function visit(item){

if (item.addition) {
  return visit(item.left) + visit(item.right)
}

if (item.literal) {
  return literal.value();
}

// ETC.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i'll take a look at checker.ts, i can get back to coding now :)